# Error:unfortunately app stopped

Tags: android

Hi I am beginner in the android I am doing small tasks like creating activities,buttons,check box etc.The code will work fine and I will get desired output.If i try to add new which may contain error I will get unfortunately app stopped then again if i undo all the changes what I did and run the code again will get same error.

what is the problem and what I have to do?
This is the code after undoing changes is there any problem?This is the main activity.Please any one help me.

```
CheckBox rememberMe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText text= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
                    EditText text1= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
                    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences(MY_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String textview1= text.getText().toString();
                    String password1= text1.getText().toString();

                    String oldname=sp.getString("name",name);
                    String oldpassword=sp.getString("password","");
                    if(!textview1.equals(null) && !password1.equals(null))
                    {

                        if(textview1.equals(oldname)&& password1.equals(oldpassword))

                        {

                            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MenuScreen.class);
                         startActivity(i);

                        }



                    else{
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("error msg");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You should register before");
                    alertDialog.show();
                    }

                    }

                }   


            });    
          button2= (Button)findViewById (R.id.button2);
          button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
              public void onClick(View v){
                  Intent j=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
                  startActivity(j);
                  }
          });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: check the stacktrace and post it here also

Comment: Did you have a typo when posting your code here or are the provided solutions fixing your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Line Causes you error..

```
CheckBox rememberMe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

The above line not out side the `onCreate()` method..place it inside `onCreate()` because after `setContentView()` only you will get the View Object.

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckBox rememberMe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

put into onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

After calling setContentView() only your layout will be loaded.So put below code

```
CheckBox rememberMe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

in onCreate() after setContentView().